# location.reload loads multiple times.. Have to reload only once on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As per client request, i need to reload particular div container area. Is it possible to refresh div container on click without ajax?

Instead, i tried to refresh the page using below code,

```
 $('li.status-item a').click(function() {
    window.location.href=window.location.href;
});
```

or

```
$('li.status-item a').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Both the codes works fine in my local environment. When i implement this in our CMS environment, getting auto refresh of the page every second after clicked the link. Not sure why its loads automatically. Need some one expertise to fix the issue.

Please check this link for screenshot,

http://teshdigitalgroup.com/team/reload.JPG

HTML Code:

```
<ul>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('single')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/single.png" alt="">
        <p>Single</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('attached')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/attached.png" alt="">
        <p>Attached</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('family')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/family.png" alt="">
        <p>Young family</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('retire')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/retire.png" alt="">
        <p>Going to retire</p>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: without Ajax? That is a weird requirement. That code should not automatically reload.

Comment: Is your code is in repeater? May be you are attaching click event to "li.status-item a" multiple times

Comment: that can done by using .load() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
   <ul>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="single" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('single')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/single.png" alt="">
        <p>Single</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="attached" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('attached')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/attached.png" alt="">
        <p>Attached</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="family" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('family')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/family.png" alt="">
        <p>Young family</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="javascript:" id="retire"  data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('retire')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/retire.png" alt="">
        <p>Going to retire</p>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
   <script>
$("li.status-item a").click(function() {
var url=document.URL;
var res = url.split("?");
var id=$(this).attr("id");
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(id)==-1) {
         window.location.href=res[0]+'?'+id;

    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Deena, thanks for your comment. But, your code loads intially before click action happens. Please check my updated link for screenshot. Had 4 icons. whenever, user clicks any of the icon. it have to refresh the page only once. Thanks again.

Comment: Add html for your question

Comment: Hi Deena.. HTML code updated. Please check.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am update my answer again .Check it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Deena.. You are great.. Need another hint from you. Is it possible to refresh <div> container instead of refreshing complete page?

Comment: Refer:http://crunchify.com/how-to-refresh-div-content-without-reloading-page-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Could you please replicate your issue in my JSfiddle. I tried your code It's reloading only once per click. Your code is updated in the below link

http://jsfiddle.net/ilaiya/72c5bvdy/1/

Code:

```
$('li.status-item a').click(function() {
    alert('Reload');
    location.reload();
});

<ul>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('single')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/single.png" alt="">
        <p>Single</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('attached')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/attached.png" alt="">
        <p>Attached</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('family')">
        <img srcset="images/icons/family.png" alt="">
        <p>Young family</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="status-item">
    <a href="#" data-ng-click="setProfileStatus('retire')">
        <img srcset="" alt="">
        <p>Going to retire</p>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```